# Show system message to user when node is published

Tags: rules

I'm looking for a way to show a system message to the author of a node, when the node gets published (by an administrator)

I think this must be achievable with Rules, but browsing the web and searching on stackoverflow did not help me out (yet).

This is what I did in Rules so far:

EVENT:After updating existing content of type Event

CONDITIONS: Content is published

ACTIONS: Show a message on the site

Comment: you could create a custom system message set up using Views, Rules, VBO, etc - I have done this for sites in the past. It's nice because it can be adapted to serve any number of scenarios within a site

Comment: Yes, I know that's a possibility but it's too much work for what I need it. On my website, this is almost the only scenario where I want to send my users a message. Though, I'm interested in how you did create your own system message. Feel free to contact me about it!

Comment: nothing should be too much work if it accomplishes the goal you desire. too lengthy for a comment, and this site doesn't lend itself to personal contact - depending the complexity the site needs, it can be done with Flags or a custom content type, and then 2 or 3 rules, 1 view and maybe a small custom module for expediency. It's really not as complicated as you might think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System messages are displayed only once and for the current user. In your case it would be more appropriate to send an email when the node has been published.

To do so, create a following Rule:

1. Event: `After updating existing content`; restrict it by content type if necessary.
2. Condition: `User has role(s)`, select administrator role and check `Negate` to make sure this rule does not get triggered for administrators.
3. Condition: `Data comparison`, for `Data to compare` select that `node-unchanged:status` equals to `Unpublished`. This is to make sure old node was unpublished.
4. Condition: `Data comparison`, for `Data to compare` select that `node:status` equals to `Published`. This is to make sure new node is published.
5. Action: `Send mail` and configure it the way you want.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sure, glad it helped.