# Use Rules to notify original author when their node is published

Tags: 7, rules, workbench

In short, I'm simply looking to notify the original author when their node goes from a non-published state to a published state. I have Workbench Moderation enabled if it makes a difference.

I've tried implementing the exact solution that was provided / accepted here (https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/159103/79465) but can't get it to work for some reason.

[image: Rules]

Solved for with the following config:
[image: Correct]

Comment: check this out, might be helpful: https://groups.drupal.org/node/97454

Comment: To Chris: please add a phrase to the end which is similar to "What may cause the eMail to NOT be send?". Then flag your own question to ask it to be reopened.

Comment: @longboardnode thanks for the link! Was able to pick through the examples there and find the solution to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) is great, but sometimes also tough to debug if things don't work as you'd expect. In your case, either something unexpected happens in your Rules Conditions, or there is some error in your Rules Action.

There are some typical facilities to do such debugging (further detailed below), but a **K**eep-**I**t-**S**uper-**S**imple technique I often use, is my ***BINGO***-trick. A sample of such rule can be found in my answer to "[Which Rules condition can be used to email a user when an admin updates their profile?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/180576/which-rules-condition-can-be-used-to-email-a-user-when-an-admin-updates-their-pr/180587#180587)". Stupid, but simple and efficient (I think).

If the above doesn't help, then there are typically 2 ways of more advanced debugging, as further detailed below.

## Rules Evaluation Log

Within the Rules **settings**, experiment a bit with the debugging facilities that come with the rules module. At least have a look at the "***Rules Evaluation Log***" (to check that the Rules logic being executed, actually matches what you expect that logic to be).

## Rules Action to display a value (using devel)

You may also want to (temporary) enable the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module, so that you can (temporary) add a Rules Action like "Display a value".

Obviously, make sure that there are no Rules Conditions that would prevent the rules Action(s) from being executed (if needed temporary remove such Rules Conditions).

## More info

For way more details about these 2 variations, refer to **Rules debugging**, as explained in the answer to "[How can I display the value of a variable inside a condition?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199080/rules-debug-how-can-i-display-the-value-of-a-variable-inside-a-condition/199134#199134)".

Comment: Thank you -- the Rules evaluation + debugging tips are super helpful as it appears I'm spending all my days in the Rules module lately!

Comment: @ChrisK merci for the feedback (and accept/+1) ... So it looks like something "BINGO" did the trick for you also, no? Though I must admit I don't understand what the actual difference is in the party you added below "Solved for with the following config: ...".

Comment: The difference is that the original was looking at the "After updating existing content" event, whereas the correct/new solution is looking at the "Before saving content" event.

Comment: @ChrisK aha, that makes sense. But if the "hold" status of your question ever gets removed, I suggest you MOVE everything starting from ""Solved for with the following config: ..." to a separate answer, and replace that phrase with something like "Using the info provided in the accepted answer, I was able to solve my issue as in the image below (ie using a different rules event".